# how to access class member (without add to reactjs state ) form contextMenu call?

Tags: reactjs

I defined class that extends react.component - and i add some member object. 
I want to know if there is some way to access the _myClassMember ( with the right context ) from the myContext function ?

{i don't want to do it by define the _myClassMember  on the state}

```
    class myClass extends React.Component 
{
      _myClassMember = null;

      constructor(props) 
      {
        super(props);
      }

      myContext(e) 
      {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        // here i want to have access somehow to _myClassMember;
      }


      // after add the img
      render() 
      {
          _myClassMember = 8;

          const itemToRender =(<div>
              <button onContextMenu={this.myContext}> 
                    "MyButton"
                </button> 
            </div>);

            return itemToRender;

      }  
}
```

Comment: `this._myClassMember` should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `_myClassMember` in the `constructor` and bind it to `this`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._myClassMember = null;
    }

    myContext = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Access _myClassMember using this._myClassMember
      console.log(this._myClassMember);
    }


    // after add the img
    render() {
      this._myClassMember = 8;

      const itemToRender = ( 
        <div>
          <button onContextMenu={this.myContext}>"MyButton"</button>  
        </div>);

        return itemToRender;

      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this will not work because the myContext is in different context and the member will be null event if its was set to 8

Comment: @Yanshof No, this definitely works. Run the updated example code. You need to change your scope of `myContext` using a fat arrow function or binding it in the constructor using `this.myContext = this.myContext.bind(this)`